# JOOQ generation adding parameters to parent method

Tags: java, inheritance, code-generation, jooq

I'm running code generation with JOOQ and Postgres. All is seems to be working, except the tables generated as classes are adding a null argument to parent constructor:

**Child**

```
private Airtime() {
    super("airtime", null);
}
```

Where as the parent/super method is:

```
  public SchemaImpl(String name) {
    super();

    this.schemaName = name;
}
```

On top of this it is adding overrides to methods in the child that don't exist in the parent.:

```
@Override
public Catalog getCatalog() {
    return DefaultCatalog.DEFAULT_CATALOG;
}
```

**The above method doesn't exist in the parent**

Any ideas?
**FYI**:Example chunk of my schema xml config (not sure it matters):

```
  <schemata>
    <schema>
    <inputSchema>items</inputSchema>
    </schema>
    <schema>        
    <inputSchema>employer</inputSchema>
    </schema>
    <schema>        
    <inputSchema>airtime</inputSchema>
    </schema>
  </schemata>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using the jOOQ 3.8 code generator ([which now supports `Catalogs`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2032)), but you're still using the jOOQ 3.7 runtime, which doesn't support catalogs yet.

Make sure you use jOOQ version 3.8.0 (or any other consistent version) across your application.

Comment: We're using 3.8 Code gen and 3.8 run time :/

Comment: Fixed -The proj sbt was using the wrong jooq version.